# ERROR: Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch: fingerprint

Tags: ssh, chef-infra, knife

I'm trying to bootstrap a node sudo knife bootstrap 10.40.116.100 --ssh-user ubuntu --sudo --identity-file /home
/ec2-user/.ssh/ihies-east-1.pem -N newsite -r "recipe[pilot_sec-update]","recipe[vmpilot]" and I get ERROR: Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch: fingerprint 16:78:0d:29:7d:5e:cf:25:01:92:df:3a:94:64:5d:b6 does not match for "10.40.116.100"
1. i can ssh with ssh -i /home/ec2-user/.ssh/ihies-east-1.pem decs@10.40.116.100
2. i cleared my known-host file
Still get the error

Comment: Check root's known_hosts too, since you're running under `sudo`.

Comment: Removing the entries from root's know host fixed that. now I get Failed to authenticate ubuntu - trying password auth

Comment: NVM had a typo in the key it works now thx! you the man!

Answer (score 0):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/78722/coderanger sugested to clear the known host from the root user as well and that fixed it